# How to bind UserControl inside another UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

The problem is that the code below which should pass a `UserControl` to Modal (is also `UserControl`) doesn't work. It looks simple, I must be missing something small here.

Here's the code

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.Modal"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<Grid>
    ....
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding PrimaryElement, ElementName=self}" />
</Grid>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.SimpleUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
<Grid>
     <Label>Test</Label>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#:

```
namespace Test.UserControls
{

    public partial class Modal: UserControl
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryElementPropery =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PrimaryElement", typeof(UserControl), typeof(Modal), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                 BindsTwoWayByDefault = false
             });

        public UserControl PrimaryElement
        {
            get { return (UserControl)GetValue(PrimaryElementPropery); }
            set { SetValue(PrimaryElementPropery, value); }
        }

        public Modal (UserControl userControl)
        {
            // userControl is SimpleUserControl
            PrimaryElement = userControl;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, the modal is showing but there's no `SimpleUserControl` in it. Something wrong with the binding.

Comment: I should be able to change the content on the modal initialization, that is why I am passing UserControl to the modal constructor.

Comment: There is no element named `self`, you probably forgot to assign `x:Name="self"` in Modal's XAML. You should have seen a binding error message in Visual Studio's Output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, it was stupid. The width and height were missing in SimpleUserControl. The element was showing but had no width and height.